# manipulating array and getting words occurrences

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am performing mathematical operations on Mysql data.

Equation for probability of word `w` for given tag `c` is like this

```
P(w/c) = count of words w where tag is c / (total count of words where tag is c + distinct words from all tags)
```

I can retrieve values from the table, but the problem is in counting the words.

Records are like this (pos is part of speech i.e. noun adjectives)

```
seq     hash                            post                                                               pos                                           tag           cat
1   78bb622642f6a28681ca15676045cabd    Marketing in every web application is essential no...   web, application, essential, big, SEO, full, stack...   marketing   Discussion
2   ec31a76d380590fff71cf7b10db0f084    I have just launched my new startup on web analyti...   new, startup, web, expert, SEO, digital     marketing   Discussion
```

I am not familiar with word counting with php + mysql. I need help with

1. How can I count distinct words in `pos` where tag = t
2. How can I count all words in `pos` where tag = t
3. How to count word `w` from pos where tag = 'marketting' and pos contains word `w`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the pos with the wanted tag:

```
SELECT pos FROM table WHERE tag = "tag_you_want"
```

Then in PHP count one specific word:

```
echo substr_count($string, 'word');
```

Count all words in pos:

```
echo count(str_word_count($string));
```

Comment: thanks, in `echo count(str_word_count($string));` what is difference if count all words and count distinct words